# Control ACL for publish topics on the fly

Tags: solace

Besides [Managed Subscription](http://dev.solacesystems.com/blog/obo-managed-subscriptions-solace/), is it possible to dynamically grant access to what topics a client can publish by a custom program, similar to how an OBO Subscription Manager works?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use SEMP to dynamically add and remove publish topic exceptions to a client's ACL profile.

You can read more about managing access control lists here:
http://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing-Routers/Managing-Access-Control-Lists.htm